# jQuery: Validate atleast one item select done in ListBox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, button, listbox

This is the ListBox and Button.

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lbTOAddress" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" Text="Send"/>
```

It has three items. During Button click event, I want to validate, atleast one item has to be selected in the ListBox using jQuery. Please suggest.

Comment: Do you mind to use RequiredFieldValidator of asp.net?

Comment: Yes. I want it in jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this

```
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("[id*=btnGetValues]").click(function () {
                  if ($('#lbTOAddress').val() != null) {
                // user has selected at least one value

            }
            else

                alert('Please select item from list.');
            });
        });   
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ListBox ID="lbTOAddress" runat="server" Width="150" Height="60" SelectionMode="Multiple">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Mango" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Apple" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Banana" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Guava" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Pineapple" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Papaya" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Grapes" Value="7"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:ListBox>
        <br />
        <hr />
        <asp:Button ID="btnGetValues" Text="Get values" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why to go for loop, if you can check directly by checking null?

Comment: this one is not calling during button click.

Answer (score 0):

> Using JQuery

```
if($('select option:selected').length > 0) { //do something }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
 if ($('#lbTOAddress').val() != null) {
        // user has selected at least one value
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this,

```
if ($('select option:selected')) {
  // something
} else {
  // else something
}
```

Comment: here it refers select box in HTML

Comment: we dont want to give listbox id there?

Comment: If you have id for select box/listbox you can give id there